# Issue with converting PDF pages to images with ImageMagick's convert (and PHP)

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a small web service to convert PDF files to a series of images.

When I run `convert /full/path/to/source.pdf full/path/to/target.jpg` when connected to the [Mediatemple (gs)] server via ssh, everything works correctly.

When executing the same command through PHP's `exec()` function, only the first few pages of the PDF file get converted. Sometimes the remaining pages are 0-length jpg files, sometimes they don't appear at all.

Also, the bottom area of the first pages is sometimes black, as if convert stopped half-way on the page.

What could be causing this problem?

**UPDATES:**

I'm using set_time_limit(0).

If I'm connected via SSH, and run the command `convert -limit area 90 ...`, it completes successfully in approx. 30 seconds. When doing the same via PHP-s exec(), it runs for ~90 seconds and produced broken images (as described above) as output.

Is there a simple way to make the convert task run with the same privileges and resources as from SSH?

*Also, since it must be really frustrating working around a server problem I have little control over -- is there a good existing web service (API) that would convert PDFs to images?*

Comment: Just a reminder : set_time_limit will have no impact on external processes you start from your PHP script, as mentioned in the note in the PHP reference manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Yes, but it appears that 'convert' is not killed by php exiting, since I can still output exec() results and other debug messages after that...

Comment: Just figured out that one (partial) solution is converting a single page at a time, and hoping that never hits any limits.

Comment: @Joel did "Debug" not yield any useful info?

Comment: Nothing that looked relevant; I basically gave up trying to get it to work on that server, and moved to another one I have complete control over. Not perfect [for me – would have liked first server], but will at least work robustly.

Comment: Basically – I believe that the server resource limits were interfering with ImageMagick, and did so in a very inconsistent manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave up trying to get it work on a shared server, and moved the app to another server - everything working perfectly now.

I believe that the server resource limits (mainly some memory limit) was interfering with ImageMagick, and did so in a very inconsistent manner. Limiting ImageMagick's memory use still produced errors, and failed to convert files successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Re your update: Can you try converting a tiny small PDF to see whether it's a memory issue after all?

Also, ImageMagick has a `debug` command line option:

```
convert -debug "All" /full/path/to/source.pdf full/path/to/target.jpg
```

I think it debugs to stdout, you would have to catch what it logs and output it.
Manual [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)

And another thing, I think to convert PDFs, ImageMagick needs to call ghostscript (I think the binary is `gs`). Can you try and make sure that is callable with the rights of the user PHP runs as? ImageMagick *should* return an error if it isn't, but you never know.

Comment: I updated the question with clarifications – was already using set_time_limit

Comment: Re: ghostscript – It must already be available since some pages are still generated.
Re: debugging – trying to make sense of it now.